# form to mail script not sending data

Tags: php, html, sendmail

I have a simple form with 3 fields, contact_name contact_email & contact_message when i submit this, the data entered into the form is not emailed to me. however if i check what is being posted i can see an array is posted:

Array
(
    [contact_name] => paul
    [contact_email] => test@test.com
    [contact_message] => D;LKF'DSKF;LSDKF
)

Here is my form code:

```
  <form role="form" name="form1" action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name" id="contact_name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="contact_email" placeholder="Email Address" id="contact_email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group">
                                <label for="message">Message</label>
                                <textarea name="contact_message" placeholder="Message" class="form-control" rows="5" id="contact_message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And here is the php script:

```
    <?php

// Contact subject
$subject ='Message from Leeds Computers'; 

// Details
$message="$contact_message";

// Mail of sender
$mail_from="$contact_email"; 

// From 
$header="from: $contact_name <$mail_from>";

// Enter your email address
$to ='test@gmail.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've recived your information"
if($send_contact){
echo "We've received your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
<? echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Follow this convention: `$var=$_POST['var'];` which is not what you're using, therefore your POST variables are not being recognized.

Comment: Thank you. That sorted it great.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to see it worked out. Like I always say, "Teach a person how to fish, feed them for life". Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to modify it to look at POST:

```
// Details
$message=$_POST["contact_message"];

// Mail of sender
$mail_from=$_POST["contact_email"]; 

// From 
$header="from: " . $_POST["contact_name"] . " <$mail_from>";
```